# Conditional Serialization of class based on class property value

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class called `Wizard`, that I want to serialize. That class contains an `Array`/`List`/`Observablecollection` of instances of a subclass called `Query`as property. 
Currently each `Query`instance is serialized like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Queries array property
    /// </summary>  
    [XmlArray("Queries"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Query), ElementName = "Query")]
    public ObservableCollection<Query> Queries {
        get { return queries; } 
        set { queries = value; }
    }
```

What I want to do now, is only serialize those instances of the `Query`class, where a certain property of the class has the desired value, somewhat like this:

```
querytoserialize.QueryStatus = QueryStatus.Valid
```

Is this possible using [Xml]-tags on the property (or any other convenient way)?

Answer (score 0):

Just select those using the linq and serialize them:

```
YourQueires.Where(q=> q.CertailProperty == DesiredValue);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure how this working in my particular issue, since the serialization is done on the `Wizard`class like this:
`xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlwriter, wizard);`

Comment: @RolandDeschain where it gets the query for serialization? just filter your query before it is passed to your serializer like i have shown in the answer

Comment: OK, that of course would be possible, but that would also mean, that conditional xml attribute tags, like described in the question is not possible, correct?